# Distribution of videos watched, given people drop out from course

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, power-law

An online training course involves 100 videos, which people watch one per session, starting with 1 and finishing at 100.

People drop out of the course, having completed *N* sessions, and watched videos 1 thru *N*.

If the rate at which people drop out has either an exponential or power law distribution, what is the expected number of views of each video 1 thu 100, given that *C* people completed the first session?

Data on number of people completing each session via [this tweet](https://twitter.com/evidenceSE/status/1732758856701186539). In practice, it's possible that the same person watch the same video multiple times, and that people not registered on the course watch some of the videos.